# The Server did not provide a meaningful reply , this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error

Tags: c#, wcf, client

I have a Client/Server Application and i'm trying to use the WCF Service that i have created but it's keeping throwing exception and i didn't managed to figure it out !!

this is the code of the WCF Server:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <services>
        <service name="ChatService.ChatService"
             behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">

          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7997/Host/"/>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7998/Host/"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="tcp"
                binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                contract="ChatService.IChat"/>

          <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:7996/Host/mex"
                binding="mexTcpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
      </services>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="behaviorConfig">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpBinding"
                         maxBufferSize="67108864"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="67108864"
                         transferMode="Buffered"
                         closeTimeout="00:00:10"
                         openTimeout="00:00:10"
                         receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
                         sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                         maxConnections="100">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="67108864"
                                  maxBytesPerRead="67108864"
                                  maxStringContentLength="67108864"/>
          <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:20:00"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

and this is the WCF Service of the Client :

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="IClient.Properties.Settings.Co_WorkersDataBaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Co-WorkersDataBase.mdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IChat" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
            transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
            maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" maxBufferSize="67108864" maxConnections="100"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="67108864" maxArrayLength="67108864"
              maxBytesPerRead="67108864" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:10"
              enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:7997/Host/tcp" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IChat" contract="CHATSERVICE.IChat"
          name="NetTcpBinding_IChat" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the connection with the server but all i get is this exceptions !!

> The Server did not provide a meaningful reply , this might be caused
>   by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeEndService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IClient.CHATSERVICE.IChat.EndConnect(IAsyncResult result)
   at IClient.CHATSERVICE.ChatClient.EndConnect(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\Desktop\IClient\Service References\CHATSERVICE\Reference.cs:line 641
   at IClient.CHATSERVICE.ChatClient.OnEndConnect(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\Desktop\IClient\Service References\CHATSERVICE\Reference.cs:line 652
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

PS: I get this exception when i click on the Connect Button of the Client Application, 
the Server is running simultaneously with the client application.

Help Please !!

Comment: Have you made sure that your firewall is not blocking any traffic to port 7997. Also make sure that there is no other program in your machine which uses that port 7997

Comment: Yes @Rajesh the firewall is not blocking any traffic from the port 7997 !! but if i have another program using that port how do i disable it ?!!

Comment: If any other program is using that port you can either stop that program for your service to access that port or just change the port on which your service can run

Comment: I got this error because an Enum was not initialized to one of the enum "valid" values, i.e. If your enum has only 3 elements, generally the valid values are 0,1,2 (unless you specify other values) Even though the variable would accept any value of the enum underlying type (Usually an Int32)

Comment: Haven you updated the service reference on the client??? Almost sounds like the the contract that the client has is different from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Security is none on the server but there is message security with client credential type windows on client - these need to match.